# maven-metadata.xml is not found in nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

Should I include anything in `pom.xml` to generate `maven-metadata.xml`? 
I am not able to find `Maven-metadata.xml` in Nexus.
Is there any configuration that I have to provide from Nexus?

Comment: It should auto generate on upload if you're using maven (as opposed to curl or upload ui).  There are scheduled tasks to cause it to regenerate in case there's an error, should be documented based on what NXRM version you're running.

Comment: @joedragons that should've been an answer

Comment: @rath I was not confident that it answered the question because OP never said how they did it and it could be a bug or some issue with process.  However, I will make an answer based around your comment.

Answer (score 2):

It should auto generate on upload if you're using maven (as opposed to curl or upload ui).

There are scheduled tasks to cause it to regenerate in case there's an error, should be documented based on what NXRM version you're running.

NXRM2 tasks: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM2/Managing+Scheduled+Tasks

NXRM3 tasks: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/System+Configuration#SystemConfiguration-TypesofTasksandWhentoUseThem